# Socket programming blocked procedure

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I am trying to create a socket between using UDP in python.

The code is quite straightforward

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

s.sendto(data_to_send, (host, port))
received_data = s.recvfrom(1024)
```

My question is, are `sendto` and `recvfrom` blocked methods?
That is, when I invoke `sentdo` will my code stop and wait for `recvfrom`, because, I am goofing around and testing client and server model on my localhost, and manually injecting random sleep times of 3 and 4 seconds to simulate real life delays, and I am getting `ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host` in case the latency is a bit high.

Answer (score 0):

These calls *may* block the thread they're being executed in.

`sendto` will block if the outbound buffer of your OS kernel is full and it needs time to become able to accommodate the message you are willing to send. `sendto` won't block because the remote application haven't called `recvfrom` yet.

`recvfrom` will block until there's something to read from the inbound buffer of your OS kernel. `recvfrom` will block if the remote peer hasn't sent anything or the message has not arrived yet.

Also, there's probably some misconfiguration happening on your side. `ConnectionResetError` may happen because there's a firewall somewhere. Latency is not related to the issue since UDP has no connections and timeouts.

Comment: How can I mitigate this? by giving more time between the requests and the supply so that I can clear the outbound buffer?

Comment: @tony9099 you should not worry about buffers. It you work with one client per thread, it's already ok. If you want more clients in one thread or absolutely don't want to wait, put your sockets in non-blocking mode.

Comment: on the contrary, I want them to block, but they are not. I explain it more in this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49076735/connectionreseterror-winerror-10054-with-non-blocking-socket-sendtodata-ho